# Right Derived Functors from Acyclic Resolution ( Ref: Algebraic Geometry by Robin Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

At the page 204 , Hartshorne defined right derived functors as $R^{i}F(A)$ = $h^i(F(I^{.}))$ , where $I^{.}$ is an injective resolution of $A$. Now on page 205 at Prop 1.2A he gives a natural isomorphism, $R^{i}F(A) \cong h^i (F(J^{.})) $, where $J^{.}$ is an $F$-acyclic resolution of $A$. Wouldn't it be just followed by the construction of right-derived functors given on page 204?

It is a natural isomorphism, that we are getting an additional fact here but is it the only thing here? or am I missing any crucial points?

Comment: Prop 1.2 shows that derived functors can be defined by using acyclic resolutions. In general, injective resolutions and acyclic ones can be different.

Comment: The definition via injective resolutions is more technically useful, due to the lifting properties, for establishing properties of the derived functor. But for practical computation, it's good to know that acyclic resolutions suffice